# Check in nightwatchjs if E2E test correctly saved to database?

Tags: node.js, typescript, meteor, nightwatch.js

For a **meteor** project with typescript and react I use **nightwatch** testing which work's great:
https://github.com/arichter83/meteor-react-typescript-nightwatch

#### a.) Checking database results via Client

Now I want to **check in the database** if the end2end test successfully added the data and that turned out surprisingly difficult. I can go via the client and look in the `Mongo.Collection` (on [github](https://github.com/arichter83/meteor-react-typescript-nightwatch/blob/78bd2b561f880bda0725ceea048f1d449060917f/tests/e2e/main.ts#L19)):

```js
browser
  .execute(function() {
    return (Meteor as any).connection._stores['links']._getCollection()
      .insert({title:"new link"})
  }, [], (result) => {
    const newid = result.value
    browser
      .assert.containsText('#' + newid, 'new link')
      .execute(function(newid) {
        return (Meteor as any).connection._stores['links']._getCollection()
          .remove({_id: newid})
      }, [newid], () => {
        browser
          .assert.elementNotPresent('#' + newid)
      })
  })
```

With this approach it is quite difficult to use my existing models and interacting with nightwatch.

#### b.) Checking database results in test

But I'd would instead use `nightwatch`'s **unit test** capability in between, but from the docs it seems that E2E and unit tests can't be mixed.

Furthermore, when [importing my models](https://github.com/arichter83/meteor-react-typescript-nightwatch/blob/ed23c82ab41309396862904d26e41235e1ed8adc/tests/e2e/main.ts#L4) in the test on the server:

```js
import { Links } from '../../imports/api/links'
console.log(Links.findOne())
```

**Typescript** throws an error that it can't resolve the atmosphere package `meteor/mongo` - so `@types/meteor` seems not to be loaded (probably meteor specific):

```
Cannot find module 'meteor/mongo'
```

### Questions

1. Is it generally advisable to check database results for E2E tests?
2. What is the most elegant way to do this with nightwatch (+ meteor)? (I also created a [Feature Request there](https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/issues/2054))
3. How to use meteor libraries in nightwatch tests?

Comment: Could you please highlight a bit more which code and behavior belongs to which of the two applications in your e2e test?

Comment: Dear @Jankapunkt, I only have made **a.)** in the code: https://github.com/arichter83/meteor-react-typescript-nightwatch/blob/78bd2b561f880bda0725ceea048f1d449060917f/tests/e2e/main.ts#L19 and using **b.)** I would like to figure out. Thank you!